# Как скрыть элемент на телефоне, а на пк оставить?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть элемент на странице, который должен отображаться только на компьютерах.

Как мне это сделать? Можно ли это реализовать с помощью css @media?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем случае Вы можете использовать, к примеру, медиа-запрос и указывать в нем максимальную ширину экрана (в пикселях или, лучше всего, в относительных единицах, типа `em`), на которой указанный Вами элемент будет скрываться либо свойством `display: none;`, либо `visibility: hidden;`, в зависимости от того, какого эффекта Вам нужно добиться при скрытии элемента.

Размер экрана, который Вы будете считать уже компьютерным, определите сами, но обычно, это минимум `1024px (или 64em)`, но лучше будет указать ширину `1200px (или 75em)`.

Это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
.element {
    display: block;
}

@media(max-width: 75em) {
    .element {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Можно пойти другим путем и указать наоборот: минимальную ширину экрана, при которой Ваш элемент будет отображаться, а на всех экранах, ниже этой ширины, он будет скрываться. Пример:

```
.element {
    display: none;
}

@media(min-width: 75em) {
    .element {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используя правило @media
 [Тут немного инфы](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-media-queries-breakpoints-media-types-standard-resolutions-and-more/)

```css
.resize{
  width: 720px;
  height: 620px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

.resize > div{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .pc{
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .mob{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="resize">
  <div class="all">Показать всем</div>
  <div class="pc">Показать на пк</div>
  <div class="mob">Показать на телефоне</div>
</div>
```